# How can you integrate grafana with Google Cloud SQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, grafana, google-cloud-sql

I haven't been able to find how to take a Postgres instance on Google Cloud SQL (on GCP) and hook it up to a grafana dashboard to visualize the data that is in the DB. Is there an accepted easy way to do this? I'm a complete newbie to grafana and have limited experience with GCP(used cloud sql proxy to connect to a postgres instance)

Comment: Grafana display the data. Google Cloud Monitoring store the data to display. So, you have to make a link between both. And boom, magically, [a plug-in exists](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/stackdriver)! *Note: when you know what you search, it's easier to find it. Understand your architecture to reach the next level!*

Comment: I'm not using google cloud monitoring metrics, I'm trying to extract the data from the actual DB. I've thus far been unsuccessful

Comment: The way I've found that works is to make the server that grafana is on accessible to GCP via public IP and connect to the data source via ssl